# Visual Studio 2015/ TFS 2013 not ignoring bower_components in ASP.NET 5 projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, tfignore

Visual Studio 2015 is not ignoring **bower_components** folder although it is ignoring **node_modules** so I don't know what is wrong.

This is the content of my project.json

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta7"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }   
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

How can I force VS 2015 to hide bower_components folder from the project's tree?

I am also strugling with TFS 2013 because I am unable to ignore folders from being tracked for changes. I have tried .tfignore but that didn't work.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. node_modules and bin folders are removed but bower_components stay. This is causing me a huge problem because resharper, intellisense, and other tools I use continually want to "process" this folder, rendering VS useless.

Comment: if you are using Git, you need to provide that to your gitignore file. Some people say that bower components should be on version control others don't. Depends on what will happen if the package gets deleted from github :D

Comment: hi @MattOverall, check the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is now 'fixed' by using the 'Hide from Solution Explorer' option which becomes available with the ASP.NET 5 beta 8 release.

[image]

[image]

Please follow [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx) for more information. Please check the "New Visual Studio 2015 Features for ASP.NET 5" section on that page.

Follow [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442) to download the update and install it for Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Thanks for the update. Good to know I wasn't missing anything obvious. Do you know by chance how the bin and node_modules were being hidden?

Comment: it is not obvious how they are hidden but it seems that there are a list of predefined folders which VS2015 ignores by design like bin and node_modules

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the answer, but this just hides the file in solution explorer. They're still not ignored by TFS and are still get added to pending changes.