# ASP.NET Core: Bower packages contains .cs files that break my application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, bower, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm using the Bower package `globalize` in a project, and that Bower package contains a `generator` .NET program that of course includes `.cs`. files. When I go to compile my app, it's trying to compile not only my custom code but also the `globalize` C# classes. Is there a way to exclude `/Bower_Components/` from the build process?

Comment: Found an answer pretty quickly via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107526/visual-studio-2015-tfs-2013-not-ignoring-bower-components-in-asp-net-5-projects?rq=1 Was as easy as adding an extra value to the "exclude" array in my project.json file. Should we close this question as a duplicate? I didn't find others with the exact same problem, so maybe it should still hang around.

Comment: Sorry, I had only been sandboxing with ASP.NET Core, so I no longer have that code example. But does RC2 still use the exclude array in the same way as previous releases?

Comment: Looks like now, I just removed the 'generator' folder. Now, all's ok

Comment: FYI, when you restore your Bower packages, that folder will likely come back